# Why does acetone give a positive test in Tollens test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

Tollens test is used to distinguish between ketones and aldehydes wherein it oxidizes aldehydes into a carboxylic acid (according to my textbook). However, another book says acetone gives a positive test so why does acetone (a ketone) give a positive test?

Thanks

Comment: What is the "another book" that says so?

Comment: The interesting thing is you have thrown out what your textbook says and have taken without doubt what the other book says as confirmed truth.  Why have not you done research of independent sources?

Answer (score 1):

Acetone does NOT give a positive Tollens test.

[This](https://www.toppr.com/ask/content/concept/distinguishing-tests-for-aldehydes-and-ketones-203128/) learning resource specifically states that Tollens may be used to distinguish between acetaldehyde and acetone. This Quora answer [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-acetone-do-not-show-silver-mirror-test) confirms. This [article](https://edu.rsc.org/exhibition-chemistry/the-silver-mirror-test/2020077.article) in the Journal of Chemical Education gives a clear summary of the way the test works which precludes ketones giving a positive test.

I would advise that you discard the book that says it does.